# Prove that $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) \log^m (d) = 0 $ if $m \geq 1$ and $n$ has more than $m$ distinct prime factors.

Tags: number-theory

Prove that $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) \log^m (d) = 0 $ if $m \geq 1$ and $n$ has more than $m$ distinct prime factors.

I know that for $m=1$, $\Lambda (n) = -\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)\log(d)$ where $\Lambda$ is the Mangoldt function.

Because $n$ has more than $1$ prime factors, it can't be prime power number and I know that Mangoldt function vanishes on numbers that are not prime power. So the result holds true for $m=1$

Now assume that result is true for $m$, that is, $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) \log^m (d) = 0 $

I want to show that $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) \log^{m+1} (d) = 0 $

I am unable to apply induction hypothesis on this to prove for $m+1$

I am aware that this question has been already [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/578720), but I am unable to understand how this comes in the answer given there:
$$\sum_{d \mid s}{\mu(d)\log^m(d)}+\sum_{d\mid s}{\mu(pd)\log^m(pd)}$$

Comment: If that helps, the last sum is $\sum_{d | ps} \mu(d) \log^m(d)$ and if $p$ doesn't divide $s$, then $ps$ has one new prime divisor compare to $s$